# File.Exists fails on file in published website

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, permissions, msdeploy

Setup: MVC Web Api app, Visual Studio 2012

Folder layout:
D:\WebSites\MySite\bin\MyDLLBin\Some.dll

My application needs to LoadLibrary on an unmanaged DLL as part of a MVC Web API application. Before doing the LoadLibrary, I do a:

```
File.Exists(@"D:\WebSites\MySite\bin\MyDLLBin\Some.dll")
```

And this returns false which means I should not do the LoadLibrary.

I tried copying the DLL here:
C:\MyDLLs\Some.Dll

and

```
File.Exists(@"C:\MyDLLs\Some.DLL")
```

returns TRUE. So I do a LoadLibrary from there and everything is goodness.

I created the "C:\MyDLLs" folder by logging onto the server and creating it. The "D:\WebSites\MySite\bin\MyDLLBin" folder is created via Publishing from Visual Studio.

I think maybe some kind of permission problem, but I have logged onto the server and set "Everyone" to "Full Access" on every folder in the path "D:\WebSites\MySite\bin\MyDLLBin" and the File.Exists still fails.

It would be better for me to deploy Some.dll as part of the publish to the bin folder and not have to create a special folder on the server to hold the dll.

Can someone suggest a fix or some other things to try?

UPDATE #1:
Interestingly:

```
System.IO.FileInfo(@"D:\WebSites\MySite\bin\MyDLLBin\Some.dll").Length
```

does not throw an exception and returns 7132045.

Comment: Try to open that file - exception in this case generally provides more information. Also check Environment.UserName before call (to know what the user actually is) and use "cacls" from command line to verify what actual permissions user have.

Comment: Thanks. The File.Open suggestion helped. To dynamically build up the path to the DLL, I was using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly and AssemblyName.CodeBase. 

It would appear that those calls put a "file://" in front of the filenames they return. I think this was causing File.Exists to always return FALSE. When I tried File.Open and the file name had the "file://" in front, File.Open returned "URI formats are not supported." The Win32 LoadLibrary would return ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND (126), so I am guessing it does not support URI formats either. 

Getting rid of the URI part made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `filePathInApp` is the string holding the path to your file from the root of where the application is running (as opposed to the root of the file system),
`Server.MapPath(filePathInApp)` will alter your directory path to be "rooted" wherever the application is running. So you may want to try `Server.MapPath("some.dll")` or `Server.MapPath("\MyDLLBin\some.dll")`

Comment: The code does what you suggest already, I just left it out to try and make the problem statement clearer. Thanks.